# tikzpicture log-log histogram

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to create a graph with TikZ similar to this image (link: http://www.flickr.com/photos/68902462@N08/8340520199/in/photostream)

[image]

It is a histogram whose axes are in logarithmic scale. I would like to have the numbers in exponential format. Could someone help me how to do it? My data for histogram is as follows:

```
(-INFINITY)-(1e-8): count=0
(1e-8)-(1e-7):      count=27133
(1e-7)-(1e-6):      count=17
(1e-6)-(1e-5):      count=95
(1e-5)-(1e-4):      count=224
(1e-4)-(1e-3):      count=1060
(1e-3)-(1e-2):      count=6900
(1e-2)-(1e+1):      count=34402
(1e+1)-(1e+2):      count=149564
(1e+2)-(1e+3):      count=877
(1e+3)-(+INFINITY): count=0
```

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Hi Ahmad. Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: I think you can have a look to section **4.4.5 Histograms** in the manual of [pgfplots](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots).

Comment: How about having non-uniform interval?

Comment: I have updated the image in the question to a new link (http://www.flickr.com/photos/68902462@N08/8340520199/in/photostream). I would appreciate it if you could upload the modified image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PGFPlots can handle non-uniform intervals and log-log histograms:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    width=12cm,
    height=4cm,
    xmode=log,
    ymode=log,
    ybar interval,
    x tick label as interval=false,
    xtick={},
    xtickten={-8,-6,...,4},
    grid=none
]
\addplot [fill=gray!50] table [x=Lower, y=Count] {
Lower Upper Count
0 1e-8 0
1e-8 1e-7 27133
1e-7 1e-6 17
1e-6 1e-5 95
1e-5 1e-4 224
1e-4 1e-3 1060
1e-3 1e-2 6900
1e-2 1e+1 34402
1e+1 1e+2 149564
1e+2 1e+3 877
1e+3 +INFINITY 0
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```